# Transform custom configuration setting using Slow Cheater

Tags: .net, web-config, app-config, slowcheetah

All examples of Slow Cheater seem to be focused on the app settings part of configuration files.

I'm curious to know if it's possible to achieve a similar output with a custom configuration setting.

E.g.

```
<MyConfigSection username="debug" password="d3bUg" />
```

Would transforms to

```
<MyConfigSection username="release" password="re1eas3" />
```

**Edit**
I've found that `xdt:Transform="Replace"` will work in this example. But If I had other attributes that didn't change how would I achieve that without losing them from the config?

E.g.

```
<MyConfigSection username="debug" password="d3bUg" apiKey="12345" />
<MyConfigSection username="release" password="re1eas3" apiKey="12345" />
```

If I used

```
<MyConfigSection username="release" password="re1eas3" xdt:Transform="Replace" />
```

Then apiKey would disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only replace your attributes, retaining other parts in MyConfigSection

```
<MyConfigSection username="release" password="re1eas3" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(username, password)" />
```

Comment: Excellent, I was starting to think no one could help. Thank you